# Using a database API cursor with JDBC and SQLServer to select batch results

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, cursor

***SOLVED (See answer below.)***

I did not understand my problem within the proper context. The real issue was that my query was returning multiple `ResultSet` objects, and I had never come across that before. I have posted code below that solves the problem.

---

**PROBLEM**

I have an SQL Server database table with many thousand rows. My goal is to pull the data back from the source database and write it to a second database. Because of application memory constraints, I will not be able to pull the data back all at once. Also, because of this particular table's schema (over which I have no control) there is no good way for me to tick off the rows using some sort of ID column.

A gentleman over at the Database Administrators StackExchange helped me out by putting together something called a database API cursor, and basically wrote this complicated query that I only need to drop my statement into. When I run the query in SQL Management Studio (SSMS) it works great. I get all the data back, a thousand rows at a time.

Unfortunately, when I try to translate this into JDBC code, I get back the first thousand rows only.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible using JDBC to retrieve a database API cursor, pull the first set of rows from it, allow the cursor to advance, and then pull the subsequent sets one at a time? (In this case, a thousand rows at a time.)

**SQL CODE**

This gets complicated, so I'm going to break it up.

The actual query can be simple or complicated. It doesn't matter. I've tried several different queries during my experimentation and they all work. You just basically drop it into the the SQL code in the appropriate place. So, let's take this simple statement as our query:

```
SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable;
```

The actual SQL database API cursor is far more complicated. I will print it out below. You can see the above query buried in it:

```
-- http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82806
DECLARE @cur INTEGER
    ,
    -- FAST_FORWARD | AUTO_FETCH | AUTO_CLOSE
    @scrollopt INTEGER = 16 | 8192 | 16384
    ,
    -- READ_ONLY, CHECK_ACCEPTED_OPTS, READ_ONLY_ACCEPTABLE
    @ccopt INTEGER = 1 | 32768 | 65536
    ,@rowcount INTEGER = 1000
    ,@rc INTEGER;

-- Open the cursor and return the first 1,000 rows
EXECUTE @rc = sys.sp_cursoropen @cur OUTPUT
    ,'SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable'
    ,@scrollopt OUTPUT
    ,@ccopt OUTPUT
    ,@rowcount OUTPUT;

IF @rc <> 16 -- FastForward cursor automatically closed
BEGIN
    -- Name the cursor so we can use CURSOR_STATUS
    EXECUTE sys.sp_cursoroption @cur
        ,2
        ,'MyCursorName';

    -- Until the cursor auto-closes
    WHILE CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'MyCursorName') = 1
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sys.sp_cursorfetch @cur
            ,2
            ,0
            ,1000;
    END;
END;
```

As I've said, the above creates a cursor in the database and asks the database to execute the statement, keep track (internally) of the data it's returning, and return the data a thousand rows at a time. It works great.

**JDBC CODE**

Here's where I'm having the problem. I have no compilation problems or run-time problems with my Java code. The problem I am having is that it returns only the first thousand rows. I don't understand how to utilize the database cursor properly. I have tried variations on the Java basics:

```
// Hoping to get all of the data, but I only get the first thousand.
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(fq.getQuery());
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("MyColumn"));
}
```

I'm not surprised by the results, but all of the variations I've tried produce the same results.

From my research it seems like the JDBC does something with database cursors when the database is Oracle, but you have to set the data type returned in the result set as an Oracle cursor object. I'm guessing there is something similar with SQL Server, but I have been unable to find anything yet.

Does anyone know of a way?

I'm including example Java code in full (as ugly as that gets).

```
// FancyQuery.java

import java.sql.*;

public class FancyQuery {

    // Adapted from http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82806
    String query = "DECLARE @cur INTEGER\n"
                 + "    ,\n"
                 + "    -- FAST_FORWARD | AUTO_FETCH | AUTO_CLOSE\n"
                 + "    @scrollopt INTEGER = 16 | 8192 | 16384\n"
                 + "    ,\n"
                 + "    -- READ_ONLY, CHECK_ACCEPTED_OPTS, READ_ONLY_ACCEPTABLE\n"
                 + "    @ccopt INTEGER = 1 | 32768 | 65536\n"
                 + "    ,@rowcount INTEGER = 1000\n"
                 + "    ,@rc INTEGER;\n"
                 + "\n"
                 + "-- Open the cursor and return the first 1,000 rows\n"
                 + "EXECUTE @rc = sys.sp_cursoropen @cur OUTPUT\n"
                 + "    ,'SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable;'\n"
                 + "    ,@scrollopt OUTPUT\n"
                 + "    ,@ccopt OUTPUT\n"
                 + "    ,@rowcount OUTPUT;\n"
                 + "    \n"
                 + "IF @rc <> 16 -- FastForward cursor automatically closed\n"
                 + "BEGIN\n"
                 + "    -- Name the cursor so we can use CURSOR_STATUS\n"
                 + "    EXECUTE sys.sp_cursoroption @cur\n"
                 + "        ,2\n"
                 + "        ,'MyCursorName';\n"
                 + "\n"
                 + "    -- Until the cursor auto-closes\n"
                 + "    WHILE CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'MyCursorName') = 1\n"
                 + "    BEGIN\n"
                 + "        EXECUTE sys.sp_cursorfetch @cur\n"
                 + "            ,2\n"
                 + "            ,0\n"
                 + "            ,1000;\n"
                 + "    END;\n"
                 + "END;\n";

    public String getQuery() {
        return this.query;
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws Exception {

        String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://tc-sqlserver:1433;database=MyBigDatabase";
        String user = "mario";
        String password = "p@ssw0rd";
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

        FancyQuery fq = new FancyQuery();

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        // We expect to get 1,000 rows at a time.
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(fq.getQuery());
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("MyColumn"));
        }

        // Alas, we've only gotten 1,000 rows, total.

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're pulling from a single table, why not use "select * from tableName" in your JDBC. Then fetch each row and insert into the target database using JDBC batch-updates. Every thousand rows or so, flush the output batch. But, no need to do anything to the input: just select *
  Maybe, I'm not understanding some aspect of your problem?

Comment: I found the following: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html. It reads: "You can batch both SQL inserts, updates and deletes. It does not make sense to batch select statements." I believe batch updates assume you are sending data in batches. I want the database to send data to me in batches. If I'm not mistaken, I believe this is what in the database world is called "paging." (The link to where the cursor-query I'm using comes from explains the problem in more detail.) I believe I have the problem solved though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
stmt.execute(fq.getQuery());

ResultSet rs = null;

for (;;) {
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("MyColumn"));
    }
    if ((stmt.getMoreResults() == false) && (stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1)) {
        break;
    }
}

if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
}
```

After some additional googling, I found a bit of code posted back in 2004:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/300865/JDBC/databases/SQL-Server-JDBC-Registering-cursor

The gentleman who posted the snippet that I found helpful (Julian Kennedy) suggested: "Read the Javadoc for getUpdateCount() and getMoreResults() for a clear understanding." I was able to piece it together from that.

Basically, I don't think I understood my problem well enough at the outset in order to phrase it correctly. What it comes down to is that my query will be returning the data in multiple `ResultSet` instances. What I needed was a way to not merely iterate through each row in a ResultSet but, rather, iterate through the entire set of ResultSets. That's what the code above does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all records from the table, just do "Select * from table".

The only reason to retrieve in chunks is if there is some intermediate place for the data: e.g. if you are showing it on the screen, or storing it in memory.

If you are simply reading from one and inserting to another, just read everything from the first.You will not get any better performance by trying to retrieve in batches. If there is a difference, it will be negative. Frame your query in a way that brings back everything.  The JDBC software will handle all the other breaking-up and reconstituting that you need.

However, you should batch the update/insert side of things.

The set-up would create two statements on the two connections:

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement insStmt = null;

stmt = conDb1.createStatement();
insStmt = conDb2.prepareStament("insert into tgt_db2_table (?,?,?,?,?......etc. ?,?) ");
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from src_db1_table");
```

Then, loop over the select as normal, but use batching on the target.

```
    int batchedRecordCount = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("MyColumn"));

        //Here you read values from the cursor and set them to the insStmt ...
        String field1 = rs.getString(1);
        String field2 = rs.getString(2);
        int field3 = rs.getInt(3);
        //--- etc. 

        insStmt.setString(1, field1);
        insStmt.setString(2, field2);
        insStmt.setInt(3, field3);

        //----- etc. for all the fields

        batchedRecordCount++;
        insStmt.addBatch();
        if (batchRecordCount > 1000) {
          insStmt.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    if (batchRecordCount > 0) {
       //Finish of the final (partial) set of records
       insStmt.executeBatch();
    }

    //Close resources...
```

Comment: I realize that my initial description was a bit verbose, but in it I noted that the issue wasn't performance but "application memory constraints." Some of the databases may have tens of millions of rows in this particular table I'm extracting from. The customer has asked that the application work with "normal" memory and network usage. Thus, I have to extract in batches. Thank you, though.

Comment: You know your environment best, but if you are simply pulling and inserting, I cannot see where the memory is being used even if you have billions of rows. Do you mean the database-process itself will use too much memory with a query that brings everything back? Or do you mean your program?

Comment: The source database is on one server and the destination database is on another server. Also, the source is SQL Server and the destination, MySQL. I don't know how to get data from one to the other without storing it temporarily in the (Java) application's memory.

Comment: I assume you're opening two JDBC connections. So, when you fetch from one, you insert into the other. At any time, you have a single record in your appl. If you change that to using batch inserts then you have 1000 records (or other batch size) ... not quite in your app, but in the JDBC code it is linked to... so the same thing. You do not need to hold the data from the source once you have inserted it into the target.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I'm doing. But if I try to extract everything at once, then between the extraction and insertion I'm holding millions of rows of data in memory, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: P.S. I'm doing batch inserts. But, honestly, I don't quite understand what you mean when you write, "not quite in your app, but in the JDBC code it is linked to." Where is the data between extraction and insertion if not in my app?

Comment: Sorry for so much to and fro. Answering you first comment.... When you loop through the cursor with next() you do not need to store the records anywhere. You read the current record from the cursor and you insert it into the target database. At that point, you are done with that record, and it is not held anywhere. Perhaps you are not doing the insert inside the fetch-loop, but why not?

Comment: Please, I appreciate the discussion. As it stands, the ResultSet is bringing them over 1,000 rows at a time, and I'm inserting them 1,000 rows at a time. Now, maybe there is a better way to do this, but I thought each individual record had to be read out of the ResultSet, one at a time. So, I'm storing the rows in a List, until I have the whole batch. When I have the whole batch, I then write them all at once to the destination database. (I don't want to write them individually.)

Comment: You don't need to store them in a list. I've edited the example to show. You can get the values into variables, and set them to the insert-statement. No need to store them anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to adopt that, going forward.