# File upload in Java web application

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a web-app that allow users to upload the data(rows) in the xls file into the database.
This is working pretty fine when we upload the file with a few rows, but then when we try doing that with a file with a larger number of rows, its performance degrades.
Could you suggest me if there is already a better tested design?

Technology  : Java, Sybase, Apache POI
Methodology : Read the row one at a time, and insert into the DB.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: About 600-800MB and has about 200k rows

Comment: Can the file be converted to a csv? If so you could split it into multiple files. Also compression would work well.

Comment: Okie, I need to see if I can convert that to CSV. I would like to know how exactly can we do the multiple file split and the compression part. I would like to try both those options.

Comment: If you're using JDBC to insert the records, are you using batches: addBatch() and executeBatch() ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070310/using-a-database-api-cursor-with-jdbc-and-sqlserver-to-select-batch-results/27107136#27107136

Comment: Nope, am not using batch as there is a business requirement to capture the status(or rather nature) of each record inserted.. There are certain rules that needs to be propogated back to the UI based on each insert and I believe by using batch here I won't be able to capture them.